# Address Iterator item

Tags: c++, iterator, set, const-iterator

Having a Vertice (Vertex class) set `s`, I want to get into `Vertice *address` the address of the item referenced by `set<Vertice>::iterator it`.
In other words,

```
address = &(*it);
```

But, returns

```
error: assigning to 'Vertice *' from incompatible type
      'const value_type *' (aka 'const Vertice *')
```

Any idea?

Comment: is `it` an `iterator` or a `const_iterator`?

Answer (score 3):

Element saved in [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is not modifiable, and `std::set::iterator` is also const iterator. That means for `&(*it)` you'll get a pointer to const (i.e. `const Vertice*`) which can't be assigned to pointer to non-const (i.e. `Vertice*`).

You could change the type of `address` to `const Vertice*`.

```
const Vertice* address = &(*it);
```

Comment: I need Vertice* not const. Is It not possible?

Comment: Modifying element of `std::set` directly is not possible. Why do you want a `Vertice*`? Which kind of modifiction would you make?

Comment: Vertice* is not created on this moment. It's a class atribute, previously settled. But, if it is not possible, I'll change the logic...

Comment: @WithoutNameZin If it's supposed to point to an element of `std::set`, then it has to be `const Vertice*`. You still could call const member function on it, but you can't call non-const member function and modify on it. If you want to modify its content, mostly you need to make a new `Vertice` to replace the original one in `std::set`.

Comment: I have a class Vertex that has a pointer to Father Vertex. Will I need to pass the father through constructor?

Comment: @WithoutNameZin Initialize it through ctor or assign it latter (by setter etc) are both fine. The point is it has to be declared as `const Vertex*`. Is there any reason you can't do that?

Comment: In fact, no. But I'll need to change many things. It's ok. I'll do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The entries in the `set` cannot be mutated by outside code (allowing it could violate `set`s invariants). If you want a direct pointer (you shouldn't) it needs to be `const Vertice*` (safe, non-mutating), not `Vertice*` (which could mutate the entry in the `set`). That's what the error is telling you.